# Access publicly to Google ML engine within REST API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I followed the following documentation by Google to create ML engine and I deployed my online predicator there:

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/quickstart

I know that it's possible to access to the engine by RESTful api as described in below:
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request#request-body

But I want all clients can access the API related to my model without OAuth or any type of authentication. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to code your server to do that. You can have your server perform the API calls. Your clients simply access a frontend you designed to provide their parameters and your server makes the actual call. All the quota/charges would be with your API key, but the requests will be done with your Client's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by granting modelUser role for that model to allUsers as follows:

`gcloud ml-engine models add-iam-policy-binding mymodelname  --member allUsers --role roles/ml.modelUser`

Comment: I added the role and it applied successfully, but it is still not accessible:
https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/personality-detection/models/svm_gs_ext/version/EXT:predict

Comment: How are you trying to access? And what is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: You can try using gcloud as 

gcloud ml-engine predict --project personality-detection --model svm_gs_ext --version EXT  --json-instances=<somefilewithjson>

Comment: @bhpupesh I want to access it via rest API, without authentication, the Gloud is separate command line tool

Comment: For that I will direct you to our documentation: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/online-predict and this piece of code in python: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/ml_engine/online_prediction/predict.py

you can also use curl

curl -X POST -d'{"instances": []}' -H 'Authorization: Bearer mytoken' https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/personality-detection/models/svm_gs_ext/versions/EXT:predict

Comment: My curl command does not work without the auth header. Note that some GCP apis only allow authenticated users. I will have to double check if CMLE is one of them.

Comment: I can confirm that Cloud ML Engine doesn't allow requests without credentials. So, you will need to pass in credentials. You might have a valid use case and we might be able to support the use case. Would you be able to share your use case with us at cloudml-feedback@google.com.